# C++ Beginner, first program. finding velocity and distance

Tags: c++, physics

Hey I'm a beginner taking an intro to C++ class, and this is my first assignment to use the formulas: `d=v0*t + 1/2*g*t^2`, and `v= v0 + g*t`. where `v0` stays constant at `0` and `g` also stays constant at `9.807 m/s^2`. I keep getting these errors and cannot seem to fix them, and im sure this code is incorrect, so can you help me figure this out?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const float GRAVITY = 9.807, INITIALVELOCITY = 0;
int time;

void gettime()
{
    cout << "Please enter the time in seconds." << endl;
    cin >> time > endl;
}  //end function Time

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float distance, velocity, time;
    void getTime(void);

    cout.setf (ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);

    cin >> time;
    while (time > 0) {

        distance = INITIALVELOCITY * time + (0.5 * GRAVITY * pow(time, 2));
        velocity = INITIALVELOCITY + (GRAVITY * time);

        cout.precision (0);
        cout << endl << "WHEN THE TIME IS" << time << "SECONDS THE DISTANCE"
            "TRAVELED IS" << distance << "METERS THE VELOCITY IS" << velocity <<
            "METERS PER SECOND.";
        cout. precision(1);
        cout<< time << distance << velocity << endl << endl;

    }

    system ("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} //end main
```

Comment: What are "these errors"?

Comment: `void getTime(void);` is declared, but neither defined nor used.

Answer (score 1):

- The name `time` of the global variable is used as the name of one of standard library function, so you have to give another name to the variable.
- remove junk `> endl` after `cin >> time` in `gettime()`.

At least this will make the code compilable.
Then, inputting positive value will lead to infinite loop.

**UPDATE:** I think removing the global variable `int time;` and function `gettime()` is good because they are causing trouble and aren't used.

Comment: Hey that actually helped, thanks alot. however im running into another problem where its not really saying anything when its run, just blank. i dont really understand what i left out or messed up in. because im looking to plug in so it says the time with the distance and velocity. but its not even asking the cout

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems mentioned by MikeCAT, you are not actually calling the `gettime` function. The line `void gettime(void);` is a function *declaration*, not a function call. Get rid of the `void`'s: `gettime();`

After that, you may see you have a line `cin >> time;`. This accepts user input, but it has no prompt, so it would look like the program is doing nothing.

As far as getting the time, it's better if you have `gettime()` return an int: `int gettime()` and not have `time` declared as a global variable.

Comment: It keeps saying the error, "expected unqualified-id before "{" token" on the first {

Comment: @Habbasi To be clear, it's the `void getTime(void)` on line 19 you need to change, not the `void gettime()` on line 10.